# famo.us: make my fonts look like iOS fonts

Tags: ios, famo.us

Is it possible to make my fonts in famo.us look like the ones normally in iOS?  It seems like my fonts never look quite as nice.

Can anyone tell me if they have faced this same problem?

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you without providing feedback, but I understand why they may have. Can you provide more details on the issue you're having? Perhaps some screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen buttons shrink and font families change due to an "implicit" small control webkit style. You may want to try adding style properties:

```
'-webkit-appearance': 'none',
'font-size': 'small',
```

The font-size doesn't need to be small, but it needs to be something other than xsmall.